# SQLAlchemy: Aggregation query in pandas sql_query

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Model: `League` has many `Season` has many `Round` has many `Game` has two one-to-one relationship with `Team`.

Total goals per game is saved in an SQLAlchemy `column_property`.

I can't see to figure out how to pass in the right query to pandas `read_sql`. All the variations I'm trying aren't working, including this:

```
pandoc = pd.read_sql(Match.query.join(Round).
                 join(Season).
                 join(League).filter(Match.round).filter(Round.season).filter(Season.league)
                 .statement, db.session.bind)
```

Which outputs the following: (I've dropped some rounds)

```
  total_goals   round_id  home_goals  away_goals finished
0             1.0   sxxx-0         1.0         0.0     True
1             0.0   sxxx-0         0.0         0.0     True
2             2.0   sxxx-0         2.0         0.0     True
3             3.0   sxxx-0         3.0         0.0     True
```

What I want Ideally is:

```
League    total_goals
league.name total_goals (across all seasons)
```

Trying to traverse from `League` downwards seems more logical, but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 1):

This worked, but I'm not sure if it's the "best" way:

```
pandoc = pd.read_sql(League.query.
                     join(Season).
                     join(Round).
                     join(Match).with_entities(func.sum(Match.total_goals).label('total_goals'), League.name).
                     group_by(League.name).
                     statement, db.session.bind)
```

Comment: can you post a generated SQL?